# PHP calculate lat/lng of the square around a given point on the surface?

Tags: php, geolocation, geometry, geocoding

Given latitude/longitude of a point of earth surface (and a distance, say in kilometers) i need to compute the top-left, top-right, bottom-right and bottom-left coordinates. No matter the orientation of the square.

I've found a nice PHP class for computing the distance between two point on the surface but unfortunately there is no function about a square (or even a circle) around a point.

Comment: There is no such thing as a square on the earth's surface, unless you're talking about quite small distances.

Comment: Now for real, the earths surface is polar, a square and a circle - both are cartesian. Think of a square as you think of a coordinate-system, justify it - so that the left-bottom corner tips zero (0;0). From there it'd rather be easy to get your way through it. However, if you want to do that with a circle, that's quite more complicated. Given a circle, I'd start with positioning the circle-mid onto zero (0;0) and now every point of the circle has to be at a distance r from (0;0) so that you easily can calculate your wanted values..

Comment: @kenansulayman to put it simple i need it for panoramio rest api: it's required to send a request with min lat, max lat, min lng, max lng, that is define a square. The idea is to show photos around a given point for a distance - say - of 5 kilometers. I'm familiar with polar/linear and other stuff.

Comment: maybe he belongs to the flat earth society.

Comment: @Dagon i lolled but cmon' be serious!

Answer (score 4):

This may work for you. The approach here is to find the destination points from the given point from due north, due east, due west, and due south. The function `getSquareAroundPoint` returns an array specifying these four points, and the function `getMinMaxCoords` returns the minimum and maximum coordinates of these points, as required by the REST API you mention (it's returned as an array of an array, in case the input coordinate is near the 180-degree meridian.) It's placed in the public domain.

The approach includes finding a destination point given coordinates, distance, and bearing. This calculation is called solving the "direct geodesic problem", and this is discussed in C.F.F. Karney's article "[Algorithms for geodesics](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00190-012-0578-z)", 2012. The `getDestinationPoint` method below uses a technique that is less accurate than the algorithms presented in Karney's article, especially because the technique assumes Earth is a perfect sphere.

```
// Distance is in km, alat and alon are in degrees
function getDestinationPoint($alat, $alon, $distance, $bearing){
 $pi=3.14159265358979;
 $alatRad=$alat*$pi/180;
 $alonRad=$alon*$pi/180;
 $bearing=$bearing*$pi/180;
 $alatRadSin=sin($alatRad);
 $alatRadCos=cos($alatRad);
 // Ratio of distance to earth's radius
 $angularDistance=$distance/6370.997;
 $angDistSin=sin($angularDistance);
 $angDistCos=cos($angularDistance);
 $xlatRad = asin( $alatRadSin*$angDistCos +
                                   $alatRadCos*$angDistSin*cos($bearing) );
 $xlonRad = $alonRad + atan2(
            sin($bearing)*$angDistSin*$alatRadCos,
            $angDistCos-$alatRadSin*sin($xlatRad));
 // Return latitude and longitude as two element array in degrees
 $xlat=$xlatRad*180/$pi;
 $xlon=$xlonRad*180/$pi;
 if($xlat>90)$xlat=90;
 if($xlat<-90)$xlat=-90;
 while($xlat>180)$xlat-=360;
 while($xlat<=-180)$xlat+=360;
 while($xlon>180)$xlon-=360;
 while($xlon<=-180)$xlon+=360;
 return array($xlat,$xlon);
}

// Distance is in km, lat and lon are in degrees
function getSquareAroundPoint($lat,$lon,$distance){
 return array(
  getDestinationPoint($lat,$lon,$distance,0), // Get north point
  getDestinationPoint($lat,$lon,$distance,90), // Get east point
  getDestinationPoint($lat,$lon,$distance,180), // Get south point
  getDestinationPoint($lat,$lon,$distance,270) // Get west point
 );
}

// Returns array containing an array with min lat, max lat, min lon, max lon
// If the square defining these points crosses the 180-degree meridian, two
// such arrays are returned.  Otherwise, one such array (within another array)
// is returned.
function getMinMaxCoords($lat,$lon,$distance){
 $s=getSquareAroundPoint($lat,$lon,$distance);
 if($s[3][1]>$s[1][1]){// if west longitude is greater than south longitude
  // Crossed the 180-degree meridian
  return array(
    array($s[2][0],$s[0][0],$s[3][1],180),
    array($s[2][0],$s[0][0],-180,$s[1][1])
  );
 } else {
  // Didn't cross the 180-degree meridian (usual case)
  return array(
    array($s[2][0],$s[0][0],$s[3][1],$s[1][1])
  );
 }
}

// Example: Gets extreme coordinates around point at (10.0,20.0)
print_r(getSquareAroundPoint(10.0,180,100));
print_r(getMinMaxCoords(10.0,180,100));
```

Comment: He's been speaking of a flat square. Your equation is about a square on a polar sphere.. or are you right? His question is unclear.

Comment: @kenansulayman: If you read how Gremo will use the information: "it's required to send a request with min lat, max lat, min lng, max lng, that is define a square", and the input: "a point of earth surface", it's clear that the output coordinates are polar.  Especially for "a distance - say - of 5 kilometers", though, the difference may be insignificant anyway.  Assume, however, that the input is near the 180-degree meridian or near either pole. Unless the "panoramio rest api" can accept such special cases, the use of an approximation with Cartesian methods may cause somewhat terrible results.